# Open Photoshpere from SD card in android to view in Google Cardboard

Tags: android, android-imageview, google-cardboard, photosphere

I'm developing an Android app where:

1. I have a photosphere .jpg image file in the SD card and I need to open it in some view, where I can swipe and view the entire sphere in 360°.
2. This also needs to be rendered for the Google Cardboard view.

I'm totally clueless as to how to proceed with it as this is my first app for Cardboard and with Photospheres.

Any help either with photospheres or with how to render any normal image for Google Cardboard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Rajawali framework ->

https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample

There you go =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the demo which I had created...

[Google Cardboard VR](https://github.com/pollux-/GoogleCardBoardVr-360-PhotoSphere)

Hope it will help yo